# Как сделать экранирование квадратных скобок в регулярных выражениях C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, asp.net-mvc, экранирование

Делаю проверку паролей на сложность, хочу чтобы в паролях были спецсимволы: `!@#$_%^&*][`

Сделал так, но не получается использовать квадратные скобки, пробовал экранировать через `\`, но тоже безуспешно.

```
[RegularExpression("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$_%^&*])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$_%^&*0-9]{8,}$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordIsNotValid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
```

Подскажите, как правильно нужно делать?

Comment: Попробуйте heх `\x5B` и `\x5D`. Не забывайте, что у строковых литералов \ нужно экранировать двумя \\ (Может в этом и есть ваша проблема). Т.е. `[!@#$_%^&*\\x5B]`

Comment: `string.Contains()` уже устарел?

Comment: @Андрей, спасибо, сделал не через [RegularExpression], но с использованием string.Contains()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте без регекспов:

```
var symbols = @"!@#$_%^&*][";

bool valid = password.Any(c => symbols.Contains(c));
```

или:

```
bool valid = password.Intersect(symbols).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/haGzcl

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var r = new Regex(@"[\[\]]+");
    var s = "GHJ[][][[[[]]][[][][]]][][][]^^hjk[][///]]]p";

    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
      Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
  }
}
```